# The identity check failed for the outgoing message

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

We have a WCF Service that runs on a Domain Server.  We have a couple a website (WCF Client) not on the domain and we use Username and password to authenticate.  And everything workes fine.

Some days when the Service app-pool recycles the website fails to connect and starts throwing lots of identity check failed error messages. (The expected identity is 'identity(http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/right/possessproperty: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/thumbprint)' for the 'http://xxx.com:8004/sts.svc/username' target endpoint.) But most days it works fine.

What could be wrong and how to resolve this.

** The clocks on the server and client are in sync.

thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

Check the clocks on the servers and clients. WS-Security fails if the clock skew between the client and server is greater than a threshold, 5 minutes by default.

The automatic clock sync on Windows Server doesn't always do its job. Clients may not sync at all. If everyone syncs to a reputable time source (NIST, for example), your problems may go away entirely.

Comment: Thanks Samuel.  The Clocks are in sync.